# Is "die" the most appropriate word choice for King/Queen's death?

Tags: word-choice

From headlines today:

[Updates: Queen Elizabeth II, Britain’s Beacon of Stability, Dies](https://Updates:%20Queen%20Elizabeth%20II,%20Britain%E2%80%99s%20Beacon%20of%20Stability,%20Dies)

[Queen Elizabeth live updates: Queen dies at 96](https://abcnews.go.com/International/live-updates/queen-elizabeth-health/?id=89519988)

[Queen Elizabeth II, longest-reigning British monarch, dead at 96](https://www.foxnews.com/world/queen-elizabeth-ii-longest-reigning-british-monarch-dead-96)

Major media choose the word "die" invariably.

It seems that the word "die" can be used for anyone's death:  average people, famous people, evil people, kind people.... For many culture this wouldn't be acceptable.

In English language, isn't there a more appropriate word for King/Queen's death (or ones that have been used in history)? Why don't people say things like "deceased" or "passed away"?

Comment: Can you give an example from your culture where a different word for _death_ is used exclusively for royalty? English has a few softer terms such as _departed_ or (as you've also noted) _passed away_, but these are not exclusive to royalty.

Comment: Anglophone cultures often have a taboo on the words _die, dead,_ and _death_. People "pass on", or "pass", and there are plenty of euphemisms. And the Queen's death is still counted as one death by the demographers.

Comment: Newspapers are likely to use ***Queen dies*** rather than ***Queen is deceased*** or ***Queen passes away*** - if only because headlinese favours *shorter* alternatives. It's just a matter of (Off Topic) opinion whether any of those are more "fitting" for the world's longest-reigning monarch (but it would be a bit much to see ***Queen kicks the bucket*** as a newspaper headline! :)

Comment: Your links are from American media. In case you don't know, she's not the queen of America and they are unlikely to show her respect beyond any other person.

Comment: Headlines are terse.

Comment: “Passed away” is a mealy-mouthed euphemism. People die, no matter what their position or rank.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've gone spelunking in the word-caverns holding [the historical synonyms to intransitive *die*](https://www.oed.com/view/th/class/17669) again, now haven't you there? :)

Comment: @StuartF You might be surprised at the measure of respect accorded Her Late Majesty, here.

Answer (score 3):

In English there is no different linguistic treatment of people based on their social status. Grammatically anything you say of anyone is correct to say of the Queen.

It is normal to only use polite language when referring go the Queen, but saying that someone "died" is not impolite.

Some people prefer to use a euphemism rather than directly talking about death (saying "passed away" rather than "died" for example) but that isn't really related to the status of the person.

The official statement of the Queen's death from her staff and family reads:

> The Queen died peacefully at Balmoral this afternoon.

So using "die" is completely appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

So, the official or traditional proclamation translated to english is "The King is dead, long live the King" and that dates to around the 15th century. In my mind, this suggests that die/dead is *not* considered inappropriate for this use case.

Comment: What is the original word corresponding to "die" or "death"? Was that Latin or still English?

Comment: That proclamation first surfaced in *French* on or shortly after 10 May 1774, in respect of King Louis XVI of France. Apart from being often alluded to in the English witticism ***The subjunctive is dead. Long live the subjunctive***, it doesn't really have much to do with *English*.

Comment: Charles VII, 1422; french was a privleged language in the English court.